# Vue page return 404 after revisit the URL

Tags: vue.js, deployment, vue-router, router, host

I'm using hostinger as the hosting server and I've published the project into hostinger by run the command "npm run build". Then i dragged dist into the file management for the domain. It works fine, but whenever i navigate to second page such as [www.example.com/page](http://www.example.com/page). Then when i refresh the page by Ctrl + R. It return 404 page such as the image below.

[Error 404 page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O2Duu.png)

I found some solution but i do not know how to apply to my project. The link such as https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/history-mode.html

As i do not know how handle with my web framework or web server level.

Below are the codes for the project router index.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import firebase from "firebase";

Vue.use(VueRouter)

  const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'Home',
    component: () => import('../views/Home.vue'),
  },
  {
    path: '/page',
    name: 'page',
    component: () => import('../views/page.vue'),
  }
]

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes,
  scrollBehavior() {
    document.getElementById('app').scrollIntoView();
}
});
```

This is the top_nav.vue code

```
<router-link to="/page"><li>Page</li></router-link> 
<router-link to="/"><li>Home</li></router-link>
```

.htaccess

```
<IfModule FallbackResource.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
     RewriteRule . index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I can't find the following in your router definition.

`mode: "history"`

Is it really running in history mode?

Comment: Sorry, I just updated the new 1 and it shows under the const router

Comment: When I had the same experience, I followed the URL below.
https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/history-mode.html
But that was possible because I knew what a Web server was.
Find out if Hostinger uses Apache or Nginx.
https://www.hostinger.com/how-to/do-you-use-nginx-on-your-servers

Comment: Thank you so much Kako-jun! I found out that hostinger using both and so I just use Apache which install it to my project and now there is 1 folder in my project which is named "Blog" then i saw the .htaccess so i copy and paste from router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/history-mode.html then i tot it should be working but no. Is there anything should be add before deploy.

Comment: In my case it was Nginx, so I don't know much about Apache. I have never used Hostinger.
Is .htaccess enabled? Please google with `AllowOverride`.

Comment: Thank you so much Kako-jun !!!! I just solved that issue.